# What plugins are safe to disable on Android Studio to make it lighter?

Tags: memory, plugins, android-studio

I installed Android Studio, it has lots of plugins enabled by default and disabling them makes the program start much faster. 
I'm sure I don't need all of that since I'm only a student at the moment, I'm also working with Java only.

Can someone give a brief explaination on what every plugin does and if theyre safe to disable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All plugins can be disabled with some lose of functionality,
so this is up to you to decide.
Plugins which provide a great deal of functionality such as an entire language
support should be prime candidates.

A [user testimony](https://np.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/7sxhig/android_studio_slower_when_using_kotlin/dt88pgn/?st=jnmp3zkc&sh=a4b62745)
says:

> Go to preferences > plugins > and disable everything you don't need. I disabled "Android APK Support", "Android Games", "Android NDK", "App Links Assistant", "CVS", "EditorConfig", "Firebase " (all of them), "GitHub", "Google " (all of them), "hg4idea", "Settings repository", "Subversion integration", "Task management", "Terminal", "Test recorder", "TestNG", and "YAML". Goes real fast now.

[Another article](https://android.jlelse.eu/is-your-android-studio-always-slow-heres-how-to-speed-up-immediately-326ef9238024?gi=21532f365cce)
lists:

Android APK Support, 
Android Games, 
Android NDK, 
App Links Assistant, 
Copyright, 
Coverage, 
CVS Integeration, 
Editor Config, 
Fabric for Android Studio, 
Firebase (App Indexing, Services, Testing), 
Github, 
Google (Cloud Tools Core, Cloud Tools for Android, Developer Samples, Login, Services), 
Markdown Support, 
Mercurial integration, 
hg4idea, 
Settings repository, 
Subversion integration, 
Task management, 
Test recorder, 
TestNG-J, 
YAML.

Comment: Yeah, what I was asking was, are there any plugins that I'd use by only developing basic apps in java? Everything seems superflous by its name at the moment.

Comment: The above plugins were recommended for removal for gaining performance. If later on you find out that you would like one of them back, just enable it again.

Comment: What I kept is: Android APK and NDK, Gradle, Groovy, l18n for java, IntelliLang, Java Bytecode Decompiler, Java Stream Debugger, JUnit, Properties Support, Smali Support, Terminal. 

But I'm really not sure if I need those.

Comment: That's for you to decide, based on what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the "org.jetbrains.andriod" issue from disabling some plugins. After some tweaking this were safe for me (from my .config/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/disabled_plugins.txt file):

- Subversion
- com.android.tools.apk
- com.android.tools.ndk
- com.google.appindexing
- com.google.cluestick.studioclient
- com.google.gct
- com.google.gct.core
- com.google.gct.login
- com.google.gct.test.recorder
- com.google.gct.testing
- com.google.services.firebase
- com.google.urlassistant
- com.intellij.copyright
- com.intellij.tasks
- com.jetbrains.changeReminder
- hg4idea
- org.editorconfig.editorconfigjetbrains
- org.jetbrains.plugins.github
- org.jetbrains.plugins.yaml
- org.jetbrains.settingsRepository